# How to check origen app creates known-good flows correctly?

Tags: origen-sdk

The Origen docs are very good when documenting [test program flow creation](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/flows/) for sure but I don't see details on how to implement unit level tests for known good flows.  As our application gains users, we need to ensure the application uses best known methods for software quality.

thx

Comment: See the answer given to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687607/apps-and-plugin-revisions-making-an-origen-app-production-ready